# Message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, nodemailer

I'm currently having some issues sending mail from my droplet. I can confirm this works in my local. I'm using the same settings except for including the `name` option in the transport to include my domain name. The emails are not making it to the recipient nor the spam folder.

UPDATE: Even removing the `name` option gives the same outcome.

This is my response

```
{
    accepted: [ 'toemail@email.com' ],
    rejected: [],
    envelopeTime: 176,
    messageTime: 337,
    messageSize: 27416,
    response: '250 2.0.0 OK <31ccdd12-a4f2-bf72-9064-b7a3a7857eb8@mydomain.com> 
    [Hostname=microsoft365hostname]',
    envelope: { from: 'email@mydomain.com', to: [ 'toemail@email.com' ] },
    messageId: '<31ccdd12-a4f2-bf72-9064-b7a3a7857eb8@mydomain.com>'
}
```

Here is my transport object

```
function getTransporter() {
    return nodemailer.createTransport({
        name: "mydomain.com",
        host: "smtp.office365.com",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
            user: user,
            pass: pass
        },
        tls: true,
    });
}
```

Here is my UFW

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
27017                      ALLOW       //mypersonalipaddress for mongo           
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

587                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
587 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

I can also confirm that Digital Ocean told me ports 25 and 587 are not being blocked.

If my droplet IP was blacklisted would the mail atleast make it to spam folder ? I ran a scan on my droplet IP and found there was 3 places who had it blacklisted probably to do with when I was changing my Nameservers from godaddy to Digital Ocean. Since then, I am currently using Godaddy's NS and just pointing an A record to my droplet IP.

UPDATE :

> 

```
Sender: support@mydomain.org
Recipient: myemail@yahoo.com

Received -> Processed -> Not delivered

Status: Office 365 received the message that you specified, but couldn't 
deliver it to the recipient (myemail@yahoo.com‎) due to the following 
error:<br /><br /><b>Error:</b> ‎The message was not delivered.‎<br /><br 
/>A non-delivery report (NDR) message was sent to ‎‎support@mydomain.org‎. 
The NDR might provide more details about why the email message wasn't 
delivered and how to fix the issue.

More information: <div>Ask the sender (‎support@mydomain.org‎) to follow 
the instructions in the NDR to fix this issue. The NDR might also 
include specific information for email admins. If the sender is unable 
to fix the issue, ask them to forward you the NDR and then follow the 
guidance for email admins.</div>

Date (UTC-05:00) | Event | Detail |
------------------------------------
10/31/2021, 4:16 PM | Fail | The message was not delivered.

More information
Message ID:<7e6d8c35-7824-6df7-bb08-236af8fbe9ee@mydomain.org>
Message size | From IP | To IP
‎28.17‎ KB | mydropletip | null
```

UPDATE:

I found the NDR emails:

> Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider
> rejected it.
>
> Remote Server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access
> denied, traffic not accepted from this IP

UPDATE: Instead of dealing with this, I decided to just utilize send grid and authorize my domain. I was able to get email working inside my droplet using their simple API. I have a feeling the droplet's IP address was blacklisted. They do try to deter people away from using droplet as mail service. I understand why now.

Comment: Are there any log files/entries you can check on the side of the smtp server? Fo example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/message-trace-scc?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: No problem @KenWhite